# C++: how to read the user input using a c-string two times?

Tags: c++

I want to input

```
1 2
3 4 5
```

a: 1 2
b: 3 4 5
If I use this way, I will get b is also 1 2, I tried cin.ignore(), it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   char a[3];
   char b[5];   
   cin>>a;
   cin>>b;
   cout<<b[0]<<endl; 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is spaces. Once you hit a space that is all you read into the variable using this method.

Comment: Yes, but is there another way to do this? getline() also cannot work.

Comment: `operator>>` ignores leading whitespace, and then stops reading on whitespace. Whitespace includes line breaks.  So `cin>>a;` reads just `1`, and then `cin>>b;` reads just `2`. If you want to read lines that have spaces in them, use `cin.getline()` or `std::getline()` instead.

Comment: ***getline() also cannot work*** It should

Comment: If you use getline, don't forget to allocate space for the '\0' at the end of each string. You should have at least `char a[4]` and `char b[6]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop to read an array of characteres and to stop that loop, choose some character as a mark (but you will have to use `Enter` after it) or use `EOF` which can be occur by `ctrl+d` on linux or `ctrl+z` on windows, as follows

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    char a[50];//to hold an array of 49 chars
    int i{};
    char end {'a'};//non space char
    while( std::cin >> a[i] && a[i] != end)
        i++;

    a[i] = '\0';
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Or use `std::getline()`. It's better. You won't need a thing but an `Enter`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(){
    char a[50];
    std::string temp{};
    std::getline(std::cin, temp);
    int i{ -1 };
    while( ++i < temp.size()) a[i] = temp[i];
    a[i] = '\0';
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```